# Flash movie that reads html values and rotates them every 10 seconds

Tags: html, flash, variables, rotation

I was wondering if it is possible to create a flash movie that rotates values that are stored in HTML. For example if i have these 3 containers:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <img src="someimage1" />
    <span class="text1">text1</span>
    <span class="text2">text2</span>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
    <img src="someimage2" />
    <span class="text1">text1</span>
    <span class="text2">text2</span>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
    <img src="someimage3" />
    <span class="text1">text1</span>
    <span class="text2">text2</span>
</div>
```

I want to have some flash movie rotate these values every 10 seconds. I don't want to program it hard into flash, it has to be variable. It has to display the first set, then after 10 sec the second, and so on.

Maybe if it is possible something that stops the toggle, and skip to just the second, or just the third.

I also don't want to use javascript to do this (jQuery etc.), because this conflicts with another timer on the website.

Is there a way of doing this?

If someone could help me get a good resource for this i would be glad, as i have no knowledge of flash, and i have searched the net but just can't find what i am looking for.

Thank you guy!

Comment: "conflicts with another timer on the website"? What does this mean?

Comment: I have a website that needs to be updated every second, something like stocks. The timer for that is set on every second. When i use jQuery to make the banner change, with a nice face effect, it halts the other script. I think the fade effect of jQuery is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up how to use ExternalInterface. You can call any Javascript you like from Flash/Flex, and you can call any exposed method in your movie from the browser.

Comment: Thank you i figured out how to work with the ExternalInterface. This works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Flash finds HTML tough, and your use of element class attributes make me suspect that you might find that Flash would find this kind of rendering tricky. In my most generous moments, I would say that CSS support in Flash is basic and buggy.